# Гоголь и его пьеса

Tags: литература

Какую из пьес Н.В. Гоголя его собственный персонаж из произведения «Театральный разъезд после представления новой комедии» презрительно называет «побасёнками»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по монологу автора - "Ревизор": «Как я рад, что так много мнений, что у нас народ неоднородный. Только обидно мне оттого, что не увидели они одного честного и благородного лица в пьесе, который был. Это был смех. Мне кажется, что тот, кто льёт горькие, глубокие, душевные слёзы, как раз и более всего в жизни смеётся».

Comment: Эту цитату обычно приводят в учебниках при изучении "Ревизора"

Answer (score 0):

А Вы прочитайте. Там все есть.
http://az.lib.ru/g/gogolx_n_w/text_0082.shtml